# java awt window keeps closing when I want it to keep still open

Tags: java, modal-dialog, awt

everyone. I have a problem with my java.awt app.

I am using the code to make a contouring graph.
When I run the main function itself in the code for contouring, it runs fine without closing but whenever I want to test it makeing Junit testcase, it keeps closing while I want it to keep opened.

Following is the original code for contouring

```
import java.awt.*;

public class ColorContourPlot
extends Frame
implements Runnable
{

public ColorContourPlot()
{
    // {{INIT_CONTROLS
    setLayout( null );
    addNotify();
    resize( insets().left + insets().right + 545, insets().top + insets().bottom + 346 );
    BackButton = new java.awt.Button( "<<" );
    BackButton.reshape( insets().left + 40, insets().top + 288, 50, 29 );
    add( BackButton );
    ForButton = new java.awt.Button( ">>" );
    ForButton.reshape( insets().left + 116, insets().top + 288, 50, 29 );
    add( ForButton );

    setTitle( "Color Contour Plot" );

    menuBar1 = new java.awt.MenuBar();

    menu1 = new java.awt.Menu( "Options" );
    menu1.add( "Contour Resolution" );
    menuBar1.add( menu1 );
    setMenuBar( menuBar1 );

    show();

    captureMode = true;
    javaVersion = new String( getJavaVersion() );

    Rectangle R = bounds();
    contourCanvas = new ColorContourCanvas( this );
    int yoffset = insets().top + insets().bottom;
    int xoffset = insets().left + insets().right;

    if ( !captureMode )
    {
        contourCanvas.reshape( insets().left + 5, insets().top + 5, R.width - xoffset - 10, R.height - yoffset - 10 );
        BackButton.hide();
        ForButton.hide();

    }
    else
    {
        contourCanvas.reshape( insets().left + 5, insets().top + 5, R.width - xoffset - 10, R.height - yoffset - 60 );
        if ( javaVersion.equals( "1.1" ) )
        {
            yoffset = 5;
        }
        BackButton.reshape( insets().left + 40, R.height - yoffset - 35, 50, 29 );
        ForButton.reshape( insets().left + 116, R.height - yoffset - 35, 50, 29 );

    }

    add( contourCanvas );

    resDialog = new ContourResolutionDialog( this, this, false );
    resDialog.hide();

    contourData = new java.util.Vector( 10 );
    currentFrame = 0;
    RunningAsThread = false;
}

java.awt.Button BackButton;

java.awt.Button ForButton;

java.awt.MenuBar menuBar1;

java.awt.Menu menu1;

public synchronized void show()
{
    move( 50, 50 );
    super.show();
}

public void repaint()
{
    Rectangle R = bounds();
    int yoffset = insets().top + insets().bottom;
    int xoffset = insets().left + insets().right;

    if ( !captureMode )
    {
        if ( contourCanvas != null )
        {
            contourCanvas.reshape( insets().left + 5, insets().top + 5, R.width - xoffset - 10, R.height - yoffset
                - 10 );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( contourCanvas != null )
        {
            contourCanvas.reshape( insets().left + 5, insets().top + 5, R.width - xoffset - 10, R.height - yoffset
                - 60 );
            if ( javaVersion.equals( "1.1" ) )
            {
                yoffset = 5;
            }
            BackButton.reshape( insets().left + 40, R.height - yoffset - 35, 50, 29 );
            ForButton.reshape( insets().left + 116, R.height - yoffset - 35, 50, 29 );

        }
    }
    super.repaint();
}

public boolean handleEvent( Event event )
{
    if ( event.id == Event.WINDOW_DESTROY )
    {
        if ( !RunningAsThread )
        {
            hide(); // hide the Frame
            dispose(); // free the system resources
            System.exit( 0 ); // close the application
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            hide();
            return true;
        }
    }

    if ( event.target == BackButton && event.id == Event.ACTION_EVENT )
    {
        BackButton_Clicked( event );
        return true;
    }
    if ( event.target == ForButton && event.id == Event.ACTION_EVENT )
    {
        ForButton_Clicked( event );
        return true;
    }
    return super.handleEvent( event );
}

public boolean action( Event event, Object arg )
{
    if ( event.target instanceof MenuItem )
    {
        String label = (String) arg;
        if ( label.equalsIgnoreCase( "Contour Resolution" ) )
        {
            ContourResolution_Action( event );
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.action( event, arg );
}

void ForButton_Clicked( Event event )
{
    if ( currentFrame < contourData.size() )
    {
        currentFrame++;
        contourCanvas.setData( (double[][]) ( contourData.elementAt( currentFrame - 1 ) ) );

    }
}

void BackButton_Clicked( Event event )
{
    if ( currentFrame > 1 )
    {
        currentFrame--;
        contourCanvas.setData( (double[][]) ( contourData.elementAt( currentFrame - 1 ) ) );

    }
}

void ContourResolution_Action( Event event )
{
    resDialog.setResolution( contourCanvas.getResolution() );
    resDialog.show();
}

public void dialogDismissed( Dialog d )
{
    if ( d == resDialog )
    {
        int panelCount = resDialog.getResolution();
        contourCanvas.setResolution( panelCount );
        contourCanvas.repaint();
    }
}

public void setCaptureMode( boolean M )
{
    captureMode = M;
    contourData.removeAllElements();
    currentFrame = 0;
}

public void reset()
{
    contourData.removeAllElements();
    currentFrame = 0;
}

public void setDataRange( double dMin, double dMax )
{
    contourCanvas.setDataRange( dMin, dMax );
}

public void setData( double[][] inputData )
{
    if ( captureMode )
    {
        contourData.addElement( inputData );
        if ( contourData.size() == 1 )
        {
            contourCanvas.setData( inputData );

            currentFrame = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        contourCanvas.setData( inputData );
    }
}

public void setData( double[] inputData, int xDataCount, int yDataCount )
{
    double[][] data = new double[xDataCount][yDataCount];
    int i;
    int j;
    for ( i = 0; i < xDataCount; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < yDataCount; j++ )
        {
            data[i][j] = inputData[j + i * yDataCount];
        }
    }
    setData( data );
}

public void run()
{
    RunningAsThread = true;
    show();
}

public String getJavaVersion()
{
    java.util.Properties P = System.getProperties();

    java.util.StringTokenizer Tok = new java.util.StringTokenizer( P.getProperty( "java.version", null ), "." );

    String version;
    String p1, p2;
    if ( Tok.countTokens() > 1 )
    {
        p1 = Tok.nextToken();
        p2 = Tok.nextToken();
        version = p1 + "." + p2;
    }
    else
    {
        version = "1.0";
    }
    return version;
}

static public void main( String args[] )
{
    double[][] data = new double[5][5];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {

        for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
        {
            data[i][j] = ( i * 40 ) + j;
        }
    }

    data[3][4] = 200000;
    data[2][4] = 200000;
    data[1][4] = 200000;
    data[4][4] = 200000;
    data[0][4] = 200000;

    ColorContourPlot M = new ColorContourPlot();
    M.setVisible( true );
    M.setData( M.setup2Ddata2( data ) );
}

private double[][] setup2Ddata( int n )
{
    double[][] data = new double[n][n];
    int i;
    int j;
    double x;
    double y;

    double a = -3.0; // create data for surface plot
    double b = 3.0;
    double c = -7.0;
    double d = 9.0;

    double hx = ( b - a ) / ( (double) n );
    double hy = ( d - c ) / ( (double) n );

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {

        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            data[i][j] = ( i * 40 ) + j;
        }
    }

    data[3][10] = 0;
    data[20][30] = 85000;

    return data;

}

public double[][] setup2Ddata2( double[][] data )
{
    double[][] data2Paint = new double[data.length][data[0].length];
    int i;
    int j;
    double x;
    double y;

    double a = -3.0; // create data for surface plot
    double b = 3.0;
    double c = -7.0;
    double d = 9.0;

    for ( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
    {

        for ( j = 0; j < data.length; j++ )
        {
            data2Paint[i][j] = data[i][j];
        }
    }

    return data2Paint;

}

boolean RunningAsThread;

boolean captureMode;

public ColorContourCanvas contourCanvas;

ContourResolutionDialog resDialog;

String javaVersion = new String();

java.util.Vector contourData;

int currentFrame;
}
```

And Following is my code for jUnit test

```
public class TestGraph
{

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass()
    throws Exception
{
}

@Test
public void test()
    throws IOException
{
    ColorContourPlot M = new ColorContourPlot();

    double[][]  data = new double[5][5];
    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = (i*40) + j;
        }
    }

    data[3][4] = 200000;
    data[2][4] = 200000;
    data[1][4] = 200000;
    data[4][4] = 200000;
    data[0][4] = 200000;

    M.setData(M.setup2Ddata2(data));
    M.setVisible(true);
    M.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you want ? can you go in depth ?

Comment: @Mr.VishalJGajera, Sorry if my question was ambiguous.  I want the new graph window to keep opened in the Junit test but it kept closing itself after very short pop up.

Comment: Are you sure that the reason why your dialog closes is not that the test that created it has finished running ? However, although I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, you can make your dialog [modal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#Dialog-java.awt.Dialog-java.lang.String-boolean-); it will block the execution until you close it.

Comment: @SantiBailors, Thanks for your suggestion. What I am trying to accomplish is  to keep the new graph window opened even after running Junit test like the main function in contouring main function so that I can see the graph. Can you give me an example to make a dialog modal?

Comment: Unit test and visual inspection is a difficult thing, especially when you have a build server in the loop (who is going to close the window that opens on the build server?). Instead of making your dialog modal, you could include a `Thread.sleep()`, that might slow down your build server, but it will not hang the build.

Comment: @user5497424 Understood. Then making the dialog modal should do. Just keep in mind that if it's your test that creates the dialog, the test will always be running as long as the dialog is visible; the execution will be stuck at the `setVisible` call; after you close the dialog, the statements immediately following your `setVisible` statement will be executed. If you are running your test from an automated build that needs to run unattended the "modal" workaround of course won't work and you should prefer @Timo solution. For an example of making a dialog modal see the link in my first comment.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).